# Why tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: do not belong to the same protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, protocols

I know this can be a silly question, but in terms of design, why Apple put this two methods in separate protocols?

How can the class and the height of a cell be a different responsibility?

Comment: Because one is responsible for data source, one is responsible for UI maybe?

Comment: The question is why Data and UI representation should be on the same protocol? don't get me wrong just trying to understand your logic

Comment: please, read the comment to the @thibaut answer.

Comment: I have the same question back when I was having difficulty computing the tableviewcells height dynamically... the answer below is correct @thibaut, another reason is MVC architecture, you will appreciate it more soon enough..

Answer (score 0):

It is no the class and the height, it is the content (aka datasource) and the height (part of the UITableView delegate).

For a quick example, let's say you have subclass UITableviewCell and define all your labels and stuff in your custom class.
The only thing you will have to do with cellForRowAtIndexPath is to plug your datasource and fill every element of the cell.

HeightForRowAtIndexPath is just a little part of the bigger UITableView delegate which is more about dealing with actions on the cell (selection, deselection, editing) than ui.

The doc is pretty clear about it though :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/

One is a delegate, the other is not.

Comment: The `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is in charge to create (or reuse) a cell. So is his responsibility to create the right instance of a cell. On the other hand, the delegate is in charge to specify the height of the cell. How can, the delegate, know the height of a cell without know the class?
In other terms: I cannot modify the datasource (creating a different cell) without changing the delegate (the height) and the delegate should know the exact class. :(

Comment: What do you mean by the delegate should know the exact class?
If you subclass UITableviewCell you have to register the class (i do it in viewWillAppear).
I don't understand your issue, you're the one providing the height.

Comment: Scenario: the delegate and the datasource are implemented by two separate classes. The datasource implement the method `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath` returning an instance of class `x`.
Now the delegate should implement the `tableView:HeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. How can it calculate the required height without knowing the exact class returned by the `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: ok so usually we do things like this :

    tableview?.delegate = self
   tableview?.dataSource = self

meaning instead of assigning self to the delegate and datasource you simply put another class.
The only thing that needs to know the exact class and whathever attribute you want to specify is the tableview itself

Comment: I can understand that you use the same class as a `delegate` and `datasource`, but this is not an answer to the question. I think that the `height` and the `cell` should be part of the same protocol

Comment: I'm telling you that you can use different classes for delegate and datasource

Comment: the delegate does not decide anything, you're the one setting up the height of the cell

Comment: hum..I'm sorry but seems we are not going anywhere. When your class implements the `tableView:HeightForRowAtIndexPath:` you have to return the height for the cell. And you should do you without know the class of the cell, because the cell is created on the `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath`, that is in a different class. Do you see how these two protocols are coupled?

Comment: I already told you, they are coupled by your instance of UITableview